# Not able to install opendr in windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

When I try to install opendr in Windows using command `py -2 -m pip install opendr`, I get error `Exception: Unable to get url: http://files.is.tue.mpg.de/mloper/opendr/osmesa/OSMesa.Windows.AMD64.zip`
and if I use `py -3 -m pip install opendr`, I get error message `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Downloading %s" % osmesa_fname)?`

What can I do now? I am basically trying to implement https://github.com/akanazawa/hmr

Answer (score 0):

> Exception: Unable to get url: http://files.is.tue.mpg.de/mloper/opendr/osmesa/OSMesa.Windows.AMD64.zip

`opendr` [tries to open local OSMesa](https://github.com/mattloper/opendr/blob/17ad5c4ee2dbb35998ff37394bb7fd0579d664c2/setup.py#L31) before downloading. If you know where to get the file download it yourself. If you don't you're probably out of luck. The code is too old  and mentions URLs that are no longer available.

> SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

This means the code is for Python2-only. [setup.py says](https://github.com/mattloper/opendr/blob/17ad5c4ee2dbb35998ff37394bb7fd0579d664c2/setup.py#L98) it's only for Python 2.7.

[Issue #19](https://github.com/mattloper/opendr/issues/19) mentions [an unofficial update](https://github.com/polmorenoc/opendr).